# YQL query redirected from target url

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, cross-domain, yql

I'm trying to scrap a website but when I try to connect to it using YQL, I get redirected to the homepage of the website instead of the page I'm trying to get content off.

Do anybody know what I could do to prevent my request being redirected or any solution to avoid this issue ?

Here is a like to the request I'm trying to perform and which is failing :
Target site :
http://gticket.imagix.be/os1.aspx
Request in Yahoo Console :
[http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgticket.imagix.be%2Fos1.aspx%22&diagnostics=true](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://gticket.imagix.be/os1.aspx%22&diagnostics=true)

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of `yql`, actually it has `302` redirect. If you directly put [this](http://gticket.imagix.be/os1.aspx) url in the browser's address bar or click it, then you can see that it has been redirected to the home page of the site and you can't prevent it.

[This](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://gticket.imagix.be/os1.aspx%22&diagnostics=true) is the yql result of the page after redirection.

**Update:**

Also remember that if a website chooses to block YQL using the robots.txt directive, you won’t be allowed to access it. So a site can reject `yql` request if it has been setup in that way and [here is an article](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/provider/) about blocking `yql`.

Comment: And would it somehow be possible to retrieve the original url destination after redirection ? Or is it simply a deed end ?

Comment: It will always redirect you so you can't be there.

Comment: Is there any way to guess the reason why my request is being redirected ? (so that I could try not to trigger it) Because if that's the URL of the page where I can get to manually, I don't see a reason why I could not come to it with any kind of trick ...

Comment: How can you go there manually ? I tried manually and redirected to the home page.

Comment: Well, when you're on the http://www.imagix.be/cinema-imagix-mons page, just look on the top of the page, in the menu, put your mouse over "Programmation", a list of two items should appear. Just click on the first item named "Mons" and there you are on the target page (http://gticket.imagix.be/os1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a followRedirects option in YQL which you can use. Check [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/Possible-to-retrieve-redirected-destination-url-/1262125821000-04b56c0e-a282-3af1-9e09-085329883dc8)